# Очередь для слота Qt5

Tags: qt, qt5, сигналы-слоты

Ubuntu 16.04, Qt 5.6.

Имеется слот, к нему идёт обращение из потоков. Необходимо сделать очередь. Как это можно реализовать?

```
//action_user.cpp
void Action_user::Action_route()
{
  DB_connect connectDB;
  connect(this, SIGNAL(AddUser(int, QStringList)), &connectDB, SLOT(AddDB(int, QStringList)));
  connect(this, SIGNAL(AddCargo(int, QStringList)), &connectDB, SLOT(AddDB(int, QStringList)));
  switch (route_signal) {
    case 1:  emit AddUser(this->route_signal, parametrList); break;
    case 2:  emit AddCargo(this->route_signal, parametrList); break;
    default:
      break;
    } 
}

//db_connect.cpp
    void DB_connect::AddDB(int route, QStringList parametrList)
    {
      switch (route) {
        case 1: addUser(parametrList); break;
        case 2: addCargo(parametrList); break;
        default:
          break;
        }
    }

void addUser (QStringList parametrList)
{
    // Запись данных в БД
}
```

Comment: Очередь вызовов? Так если слот вызывается из различных потоков, то сигналы выстроятся в очередь самостоятельно автоматом.

Comment: У меня почему то не выстраиваются. Потоки разные.

Comment: Как определяете, что не выстраиваются? Как создаёте потоки и как вызываете из них слот? Вам надо эти все моменты расписать в вопросе, иначе получается игра в загадки.

Comment: Ну тогда у Вас получается, что `Action_route()` и слот `AddDB` промеж собой в идентичных потоках функционируют. В этом случае указывайте явно для `connect()` флаг `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Comment: с этим ключём он почему то не хочет переходить в слот

Comment: Вообще я планировал из потоков собирать данные и обрабатывать результат в основном потоке, это нужно для работы с БД.

Comment: Если не переходит, значит в потоке не запущен обработчик событий (event loop). Ко всему прочему, если `Action_route()` запускается из отдельного потока, то и слот `AddDB()` выполнится в нём же по той простой причине, что объект `connectDB` создаётся именно в `Action_route()`. Главный поток здесь вообще никакого участия не принимает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, что Вам нужно, то нужно просто правильно подключить сигнал-слот. у функции `connect` есть ещё один параметр, который обычно никто не трогает, так как он по умолчанию Он определяет "как именно будет обрабатываться сигнал". По умолчанию там `Qt::AutoConnection`. Если сигнал-слот в пределах одного потока, то это будет `Qt::DirectConnection` - это, грубо говоря, просто вызов функции по месту.

Если сигнал-слот в разных тредах, тогда `Qt::AutoConnection` это `Qt::QueuedConnection` - сигнал добавляется в event loop нужно треда и когда eventloop освободиться и достанет с очереди сигнал, то он и будет обработан.

Ещё есть `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` - оно как `Qt::QueuedConnection`, но вот только вызывающий поток (тот кто эмитит сигнал) блокируется, пока не будет обработан сигнал (**я думаю, это то, что Вы ищите!**).

Пример

```
QObject::connect(scrollBar, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int value)),
             label, SLOT(setNum(int value)), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
```

Comment: пишет в консоли: Qt: Dead lock detected while activating a BlockingQueuedConnection: Sender is Action_user(0x7f9611981930), receiver is DB_connect(0x7f9611981820)

Comment: Потому что у вас получатель и отправиль в одном треде. И данный случай нельзя обработать. Но по логике он эквивалентный `Qt::DirectConnection`.

Comment: Вообще я планировал из потоков собирать данные и обрабатывать результат в основном потоке, это нужно для работы с БД.